# autofocus attribute ignored on HTML page served by google script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

The following google script creates a small website (copied from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index.html')
      .evaluate();
}
```

The corresponding index.html (copied from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_autofocus.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" autofocus onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The autofocus attribute of the button tag is not supported in IE 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I load the website, I expect the button to be focused and show "Hello world" on pressing ENTER. However the button is *not* focused and I need to click the button with the mouse. What do I need to change to make the autofocus attribute to work?

[Sample website](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyhUyDFMBNTzkcigM77e-Cmbvh44XqQ8VEFZfxjgAUAFIQz_cLf/exec)

PS: This used to work about a year ago

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed that when `autofocus` was used, an error of `Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe.` occurred. It was found that by this, the button cannot be focused. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the method for using `autofocus` for this situation. So in order to avoid this issue, how about this workaround? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

In this workaround, `focus()` is used.

#### Modified HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button> <!-- Modified -->

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The autofocus attribute of the button tag is not supported in IE 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<script>
  document.getElementById('button').focus(); // Added
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### References:

- [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The button is *not* focused with the added script

Comment: @kusi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide HTML including Javascript for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, what browser are you using? In my environment, I could confirm that the modified HTML worked at Google Chrome.

Comment: thanks for replicating the issue! If you have a google account, you go to script.google.com, create a new project and save the one single js function I provided to the default file code.gs, you add the second file I've provided as index.html and you deploy. There's nothing more I can provide.
However, I figured out that the site provided by google is not the initial index.html anymore, but a sandboxed iframe. Maybe this is the issue? You can go to the sample website I provided and look at the source code of the website  (https://gist.github.com/githubkusi/a4799f7524f00bff1fa0242891521382)

Comment: @kusi Thank you for replying. Although I saw your gist, it seems that the script of gist is different from the script in your question. I was surprised that the script was changed, and I'm confused about this situation. At first, how about resolving the issue of your this question? Because my answer is for your question and also I'm not sure whether my modification can resolve your issue, yet. After your question was resolved, can you post the script of gist as new question? I would like to support you. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: thanks for helping me @Tanaike :) The two files I provided in the question are used as-is as input for the google scripts project. The gist is the resulting html page provided by the google web server when you run the script. Google altered the script from my index.html from the project to the version in the gist by boxing my script into an iframe. You *need* a google account in order to replicate the problem. You *need* to create a project in script.google.com. I'm not sure if you did that? BTW I was testing under Chrome and Firefox, both ignoring the autofocus attribute.

Comment: @kusi Thank you for replying. At first, if you cannot understand about my English, I have to apologize. I could confirm `autofocus` cannot be used for the script of your question. So I proposed to use `focus()` of Javascript instead of `autofocus` as a workaround. And in my environment, I could confirm that the workaround worked. Under this situation, I asked whether this workaround can be used for your situation.

Comment: focus() doesn't work either, @Tanaike. Both the autofocus attribute and the focus() call are wrapped in a sandboxed iframe by google. I suppose this is the issue: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions

Comment: @kusi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand about your issue, please provide the script for replicating the issue. By this, I would like to confirm it. Because in my environment, I could confirm that the modified script in my answer worked fine. Of course, please remove your personal information. I would like to resolve your issue.